# Efficient (fast) way to group continuous data in one DataFrame based on ranges taken from another DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have experimental data produced by different programs. One is logging the start and end time of a trial as well as the type of trial (a category).

```
       start  trial type        end
0   6.002987      2    c   7.574240
1   7.967054      3    b  19.084946
2  21.864419      5    b  23.298480
3  23.656995      7    c  24.087210
4  24.194764      9    c  27.960752
```

The other one records a continous datastream and logs the time for each observation.

```
               X         Y         Z
0.0000  0.324963 -0.642636 -2.305040
0.0333  0.025089 -0.480412 -0.637273
0.0666  0.364149  0.966594  0.789467
0.0999 -0.087334 -0.761769  0.399813
0.1332  0.841872  2.306711 -1.059608
```

I have the 2 tables as pandas DataFrames and want to retrieve only those parts of the continuous data that is between the start to end ranges found in the rows of the trials DataFrame. I managed that by using a for-loop that iterates over the rows, but I was thinking that there must be more of a "pandas way" of doing this. So I looked into *apply*, but what I came up with so far was even considerably slower than the loop.
As I'm working on a lot of large datasets I'm looking for the most efficient way in terms of execution time to solve this.

This is a slice of the expected result for the continous DataFrame:

```
                X         Y         Z  trial type
13.6863  0.265358  0.116529  1.196689    NaN  NaN
13.7196 -0.715096 -0.413416  0.696454    NaN  NaN
13.7529  0.714897 -0.158183  1.735958    4.0    b
13.7862 -0.259513  0.194762 -0.531482    4.0    b
13.8195 -0.929080 -1.200593 -1.233834    4.0    b
```

**[EDIT:]** Here I test performance of different approaches. I found a way using apply(), but it isn't much faster than using iterrows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_trials_df(num_trials=360, max_start=1400.0):
    # First df holds start and end times (as seconds) of a trial as well as type of trial.
    d = {'trial': pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 400), replace=False, size=(360,)))),
         'type': pd.Series(np.random.choice(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),size=num_trials)),
         'start': pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.random_sample((num_trials,))) * max_start)}
    trials_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    # Create column for when the trial ended.
    trials_df['end'] = trials_df['start'].shift(-1)
    trials_df.loc[num_trials-1, 'end'] = trials_df['start'].iloc[-1] + 2.0
    trials_df['diff'] = trials_df['end'] - trials_df['start']
    trials_df['end'] = trials_df['end'] - trials_df['diff'] * 0.2
    del trials_df['diff']
    return trials_df


def create_continuous_df(num_trials=360, max_start=1400.0):
    # Second df has continuously recorded data with time as index.
    time_delta = 1.0/30.0
    rows = int((max_start+2) * 1/time_delta)
    idx_time = pd.Index(np.arange(rows) * time_delta)
    continuous_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows, 3), index=idx_time, columns=list('XYZ'))
    print("continuous rows:", continuous_df.index.size)
    print("continuous last time:", continuous_df.last_valid_index())
    return  continuous_df


# I want to group the continuous data by trial and type later on.
def iterrows_test(trials_df, continuous_df):
    for index, row in trials_df.iterrows():
        continuous_df.loc[row['start']:row['end'], 'trial'] = row['trial']
        continuous_df.loc[row['start']:row['end'], 'type'] = row['type']


def itertuples_test(trials_df, continuous_df):
    continuous_df['trial'] = np.NaN
    continuous_df['type'] = np.NaN
    for row in trials_df.itertuples():
        continuous_df.loc[slice(row[1],row[4]), ['trial','type']] = [row[2],row[3]]


def apply_test(trials_df, continuous_df):
    trial_series = pd.Series([x[0] for x in zip(trials_df.values)])
    continuous_df['trial'] = np.NaN
    continuous_df['type'] = np.NaN
    def insert_trial_data_to_continuous(vals, con_df):
        con_df.loc[slice(vals[0], vals[3]), ['trial','type']] = [vals[1],vals[2]]

    trial_series.apply(insert_trial_data_to_continuous, args=(continuous_df,))


def real_slow_index_map(trials_df, continuous_df):
    # Transform trial_data to new df: merge start and end ordered, make it float index.
    trials_df['pre-start'] = trials_df['start'] - 0.0001
    trials_df['post-end'] = trials_df['end'] + 0.0001

    start_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'type': trials_df['type'].values, 'trial': trials_df['trial'].values},
                            index=trials_df['start'])
    end_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'type': trials_df['type'].values, 'trial': trials_df['trial'].values},
                          index=trials_df['end'])
    # Fill inbetween trials with NaN.
    pre_start_df = pd.DataFrame({'trial': np.NaN, 'type': np.NaN}, index=trials_df['pre-start'])
    post_end_df = pd.DataFrame({'trial': np.NaN, 'type': np.NaN}, index=trials_df['post-end'])
    new_df = start_df.append([end_df, pre_start_df, post_end_df])
    new_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    # Each start/end index in new_df has corresponding value in type and trial column.
    def get_tuple(idx):
        res = new_df.iloc[new_df.index.get_loc(idx, method='nearest')]
        # return trial and type column values.
        return tuple(res.values)
    # Apply this to all indices.
    idx_series = continuous_df.index.to_series()
    continuous_df['trial'] = idx_series.apply(get_tuple).values
    continuous_df[['trial', 'type']] = continuous_df['trial'].apply(pd.Series)


def jp_data_analysis_answer(trials_df, continuous_df):
    ranges = trials_df[['trial', 'type', 'start', 'end']].values
    def return_trial(n):
        for i, r in enumerate(ranges):
            if r[2] <= n <= r[3]:
                return tuple((i, r[1]))
        else:
            return np.nan, np.nan

    continuous_df['trial'], continuous_df['type'] = list(zip(*continuous_df.index.map(return_trial)))


def performance_test(func, trials_df, continuous_df):
    return_df = continuous_df.copy()
    time_ref = time.perf_counter()
    func(trials_df, return_df)
    time_delta = time.perf_counter() - time_ref
    print("time delta for {}:".format(func.__name__), time_delta)
    return  return_df


# Just to illustrate where this is going:
def plot_trial(continuous_df):
    continuous_df['type'] = continuous_df['type'].astype('category')
    continuous_df = continuous_df.groupby('type').filter(lambda x: x is not np.NaN)
    # Without the NaNs in column, let's set the trial column to dtype integer.
    continuous_df['trial'] = continuous_df['trial'].astype('int64')
    # Plot the data by trial.
    for key, group in continuous_df.groupby('trial'):
        group.drop(['trial', 'type'], axis=1).plot()
        plt.title('Trial {}, Type: {}'.format(key, group['type'].iloc[0]))
        plt.show()
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    num_trials = 360
    max_start_time = 1400
    trials_df = create_trials_df(max_start=max_start_time)
    data_df = create_continuous_df(max_start=max_start_time)

    # My original approach with a for-loop over iterrows.
    iterrows_df = performance_test(iterrows_test,trials_df, data_df)

    # itertuples test
    itertuples_df = performance_test(itertuples_test,trials_df, data_df)

    # apply() on trial data, continuous data is manipulated therein
    apply_df = performance_test(apply_test,trials_df, data_df)

    # Mapping on index of continuous data. SLOW!
    map_idx_df = performance_test(real_slow_index_map,trials_df, data_df)

    # method by jp_data_analysis' answer. Works well with small continuous_df, but doesn't scale well.
    jp_df = performance_test(jp_data_analysis_answer,trials_df, data_df)

    plot_trial(apply_df)
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @OlafH. was my solution helpful?

Comment: @Tai The expected output is the continuous data with the rows grouped by the start-to-end ranges of the trials.

Answer (score 0):

I see a factor ~7x improvement with below logic. The trick is to use an `index.map(custom_function)` on `continuous_df` and unpack the results, together with (in my opinion) underused `for..else..` construct. This is still sub-optimal, but may be sufficient for your purposes, and certainly better than iterating rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test2():
    # First df holds start and end times (as seconds) of a trial as well as type of trial.
    num_trials = 360
    max_start = 1400.0
    d = {'trial': pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 400), replace=False, size=(360,)))),
         'type': pd.Series(np.random.choice(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),size=num_trials)),
         'start': pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.random_sample((num_trials,))) * max_start)}
    trials_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    # Create column for when the trial ended.
    trials_df['end'] = trials_df['start'].shift(-1)
    trials_df.loc[num_trials-1, 'end'] = trials_df['start'].iloc[-1] + 2.0
    trials_df['diff'] = trials_df['end'] - trials_df['start']
    trials_df['end'] = trials_df['end'] - trials_df['diff'] * 0.2
    del trials_df['diff']

    # Second df has continuously recorded data with time as index.
    time_delta = 0.0333
    rows = int(max_start+2/time_delta)
    idx_time = pd.Index(np.arange(rows) * time_delta)
    continuous_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,3), index=idx_time, columns=list('XYZ'))

    ranges = trials_df[['trial', 'type', 'start', 'end']].values
    def return_trial(n):
        for r in ranges:
            if r[2] <= n <= r[3]:
                return tuple(r[:2])
        else:
            return (np.nan, '')

    continuous_df['trial'], continuous_df['type'] = list(zip(*continuous_df.index.map(return_trial)))

    return trials_df, continuous_df
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I updated the code for the rows of the continuous data, which was wrong (far too few rows). It should read: `rows = int((max_start+2) * 1/time_delta)`. Having done that, your code runs slower on the dataset than the for-loop over the trials of the trial_df DataFrame.